# Как парсить фото и отправлять их в бота, не скачивая на сервер

Tags: requests, aiogram, beautiful-soup

Я пишу бота, хочу добавить в функционал парсинг ГДЗ, но не знаю, как отпралять картинку, не загружая ее на сервер
Если такое сделать нельзя, подскажите способ загрузить все фото разом, пожалуйста

Comment: Предоставьте ваш код.

Comment: Можете заставить пользователя бота самостоятельно на своем компьютере спарсить и отправить вам результаты.

Comment: Еще один вариант: заставить Павла Дурова на сервере телеграма разместить ваш код, чтобы они обрабатывались прямо там.

Comment: Это все варианты, которые я знаю. В противном случае вам придётся таки загружать их к себе на сервер.

Comment: @МихаилРебров Можно временно загрузить в оперативку, можно ссылку на картинку боту скармить

Comment: @СергейШ, для того чтобы загрузить что-то в оперативку бота, нужно это что-то сначала скачать, не так ли?

Comment: @СергейШ со ссылкой та же фигня. До тех пор, пока это просто ссылка, все что вы можете спарсить - так это саму ссылку... Извлечь там  протокол, домен, путь и тд